# Terraform- provider configuration not found

Tags: terraform

How to resolve below error

```
Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with module.my_ec2.aws_instance.web[0] (orphan) its original provider
configuration at module.my_ec2.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"]
is required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in
the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
module.my_ec2.aws_instance.web[0] (orphan), after which you can remove the
provider configuration again.

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

Comment: Have you tried re-adding the provider configuration as the error message suggests? If so, what happened when you tried it? Or if you were unable to do so, what blocked you from doing that? Currently it's not really possible to answer this question because you've not given any context about what you did to arrive in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "3.10.0"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "default"
}
```

Then run `terraform init`
and try running a plan again.